# Query multiple columns using one common parent column on mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following entry on database:

```
Member Table
ID: 1
FirstName: Simon
LastName: Handsome
Gender: Male

Membership Table
ID: 1
Program: Boxing
Date Started: 11-01-2018
Date Expired: 11-02-2018
MemberID: 1

ID: 2
Program: Weight Training
Date Started: 12-02-2018
Date Expired: 12-04-2018
MemberID: 1
```

I want to create a query that will return the following:

```
MemberID: 1
FirstName: Simon
LastName: Handsome
Gender: Male
Membership: [Object]
```

Where object contains both the programs that the members is part of. Regardless the number of programs the user has subscribed, is there a way to organize this in MySQL on how to query and return the member table data just once with the multiple programs he/she has? I'm no good at SQL pardon me, I need your help.

Comment: Is `GROUP_CONCAT(membership.id)` what you're looking for?

Comment: SQL doesn't have objects, it doesn't have nested data. All it has are 2-dimensional tables.

Comment: This type of thing is normally done in a client programming language like PHP, Python, or Javascript. They have arrays and objects that can be nested in each other.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer, thanks to Barmar. `GROUP_CONCAT` is the one I need.

Thanks Barmar!